# Nokogiri - Encoding Issue - Invalid UTF8 characters

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Can someone take a look at this. I think there is invalid UTF-8 characters when making this call.

`Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.next.co.uk/x502062s2"))`

If there a way around this? And is this the issue? I am writing a new open source screen scraper designed for product information capture (when a site does not supply a feed) before anyone says I am doing something a little shifty :-)

Comment: Ok somthing strange... If this is changed to Nokogiri.parse(open(uri.to_s).read) all is fine. I need to find out why though.

Comment: What version of Ruby, Nokogiri and Open-URI are you using? I do not seem to be getting any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Before passing anything to Nokogiri, you can encode the content of the page, and ignore all invalid UTF characters using Iconv.

I was using it like this:

```
ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
valid_string = ic.iconv(open('http://example.com').read)
```

You can also check "[Fixing invalid UTF-8 in Ruby, revisited](http://po-ru.com/diary/fixing-invalid-utf-8-in-ruby-revisited/)."